# Is it possible to represent any sequence as the coefficients of arbitrary generating functions?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I just had an introduction to enumerative combinatorics and we've been introduced to generating sequences. Generating sequences are series, but in this course we learned properties and operations in a very pragmatic way. There is something that got me curious: Is it possible to express any kind of sequence as the coefficients of the generating functions?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here. Given any sequence, you can form a corresponding generating function, and so the sequence is comprised of coefficients of said generating function. (Depending on the growth of the sequence, we may need to be speaking about formal power series, not actual functions defined by power series, since e.g. $a_n=n^n$ and $b_n=n!$ would correspond to the same function with domain $\{0\}$.) Which seems to make your question trivial, no?

Comment: @whacka The problem is here: "*you can form a corresponding generating function*". I've looked (in my lectures) at few methods for finding generating functions. They are basically the expansion $(1-x)^n$ and $\left[ \frac{1}{1-x} \right]^n$, derivating and integrating one series and performing the sum/multiplication of two series. With this, it's not really clear that every sequence could be produced in the coefficients of the generating function.

Comment: Any sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ has a corresponding generating function $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$. Your lectures are about finding nice, *closed-forms* for generating functions. But a GF is a GF regardless of whether or not it has a nice explicit closed-form for us to write down.

Comment: @whacka Got it. I got curious on a generating function which can't be expressed in a nice closed-form. Could you give me an example?

Comment: It depends on what you're willing to call a closed form, and whether or not you're willing to allow formal power series. If you are willing to allow formal power series, then the examples I gave $\sum n!x^n$ and $\sum n^n x^n$ work. Otherwise, with actual functions, we have to ask which special functions we're allowed to use. For instance, $\theta(q)=\sum a_nq^n$ with $a_0=1$, $a_n=2$ if $n$ is a square and $a_n=0$ otherwise, where $\theta(q)$ is the theta function.

Comment: If you take $a_n$ to be sufficiently radical the GF ought to not have closed form, e.g. $a_n=\varphi\big(n+\lfloor\ln(n+1)\rfloor\big)$. Note the set of sequenecs of natural numbers is uncountable but the set of closed-forms for functions (regardless of however finitely many special functions we allow into the mix) is countable, so of course there will necessarily exist generating functions without closed forms.

Comment: @whacka What's the meaning of *sufficiently radical*? I googled it and most of the results are about radical christianism(?!) and suffixing "math", yields something that also seems completely unrelated.

Comment: In colloquial usage "radical" means "extreme," "crazy" or "out-there." Nothing to do with math.